# Arrays containing text in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

In MATLAB, when code like this is implemented:

```
c = ['a','b','c','d'];
```

you can't really do anything with the elements. To illustrate my example:

```
>> c

c =

abcd
```

and when you do `c(1,1)` it returns `A`. But for `c(2,1)` it returns `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

To combat this problem, is there any way I could get around it? Or perhaps a different type of array?

Comment: What do you expect from `c(2,1)`?

Comment: read the docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html, http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html

Comment: Use `c(1,2)` (or `c(2)`), not `c(2,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store each string in a different row, like so:

```
c = ['a';'b';'c';'d'];
```

What you have done above is use the `[]`, which is the string concatenation operator. What it outputs is a single string, `'abcd'`, stored in `c(1)`, which is why `c(2)` throws an index error.

Alternatively, you could use [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) :

```
c{1} = 'a';
c{2} = 'b';
```

Comment: Your second sentence is not correct. The string is stored as a character array `c`, which can be indexed like any other array. The reason `c(2,1)` throws an index error is because there is only one row of characters. `c(2)` functions just fine with the original question.